# Express throw all undefined variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been tasked with modifying a node.js app that uses express, that someone else created.

I need a way to throw all undefined variables in the app. there are thousands of functions and the app just hangs. From doing some initial debugging I have noticed that each issue I have come tackled is ultimately because of undefined variables.

I don't want to get into a long discussion about error handling in node.js/express, because I understand this, but the person who built the app did not.

I am just looking for a way to throw all undefined variables to help me find them in the code and fix the issues.

TIA!

Comment: You can use eslint: http://eslint.org/demo/

Answer (score 1):

Use strict mode: Place this at the top of your JS files

```
"use strict";
```

Also, there is a node module that can apply Strict Mode to all your modules.

[Use Strict Node Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Brian, but I already have "use strict" in my files